# conceptual x86 assembly 32 bit

Tags: assembly, x86

[image]

can someone explain as to how yval = 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 10

I get lost at the add esi, 4 and after that it is all a jumble

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you get hold of a simulator such as [Jasmin](http://www.lrr.in.tum.de/~jasmin) so that you can step through simple examples like this and see what's going on:

[image: Jasmin screen shot]

As you step through the code you can see that for each loop iteration you are loading two consecutive values form `xval`, adding them, and storing them to `yval`.

So on the first iteration you load 1 and 2, add them to get 3, then store this to the first element of `yval`. On the next iteration you get 2 + 3 = 5, and so on.

The last iteration is slightly tricky as the source values are loaded from the last element of `xval` and the the first element of `yval`, so you get 7 + 3 = 10.

Comment: Yes, a simulator is certainly useful if you can't figure it out yourself.  For me, the sign of a good programmer is his ability to mentally simulate what the program does.  And I agree sometimes one cannot because the code is complicated or surprising.   But mental simulation beats a real simulation when reading code in most circumstances.

Comment: @IraBaxter: you're probably right, but the OP is evidently a beginner and is struggling to understand the code, so a simulator might help them to clear a few intellectual hurdles.

Comment: agreed, but he should have a goal of learning to not need one.

Comment: could you explain the contents then of xval? I assume it to be 2, 3, 4, ...? But I am a bit unsure

Comment: `xval` doesn't change - the code only reads from `xval` and writes to `yval`. Did you try running this with a simulator like Jasmin above, as suggested ?

Comment: No I have not yet, but in this case would xval just be equal to lengthof yval which is 7?

Comment: `xval` is an *array* of 7 elements, as is `yval`. `xval` contains the 7 values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` as specified by the `DWORD` directive. The loop reads values from the `xval` array and writes values to the `yval` array. Seriously, install a simulator and step through the code - it will make everything a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

ESI contains a pointer to the array of 32 bit (DWORD) values xval.

"add esi, 4" advances ESI by 4 bytes, e.g., the size of a DWORD; if this were C, it would be ESI+=sizeof(DWORD);  thus advancing ESI to point to the next slot in the array xval.

When in doubt, get an instruction set manual, and study it carefully; there are spectactularly good ones at the intel web site. Yes, they are actually daunting in size, and the first time you open one will likely cost you a few hours as you stumble around in the manuals trying to get all the pieces in place.  Its a hugely valuable experience if you intend to do any serious assembly language programming.

I'll leave the rest to you.